# Attempting to center a telerik control in a bootstrap popup

Tags: css, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to center the radmediaplayer telerik control, but to no avail. Please help thank you.

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlModal3" runat="server" role="dialog" CssClass="modal fade">
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlInner3" runat="server" CssClass="modal-dialog" >
        <asp:Panel ID="pnlContent4" CssClass="modal-content" runat="server">
            <asp:Panel runat="server" class="modal-header">                        
                <h4 class="modal-title" >Clip Player</h4>
            </asp:Panel>
            <asp:panel runat="server" class="modal-body">
                <telerik:RadScriptManager runat="server" ID="RadScriptManager2" />
                <div style="text-align:center;">
                    <telerik:RadMediaPlayer ID="ClipPlayer" runat="server" AutoPlay="true" Height="400px" Width="400px" DestroyOnClose ="true">
                    </telerik:RadMediaPlayer>
                </div>
            </asp:panel>
            <asp:panel runat="server" class="modal-footer">
                <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Text="Close" OnClick="btnClose_Click" class="btn btn-default"/>
            </asp:panel>
        </asp:Panel>
    </asp:Panel>
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, two generic issues:

- RadMediaPlayer does not have a DestroyOnClose property. RadWindow has.
- The script manager should be your first control inside the .

Back to your question - what exactly is not working? have you tried setting margin: auto to the div element that is the media player control? This worked for me in a basic setup:

```
<div>
    <telerik:RadMediaPlayer ID="ClipPlayer" CssClass="centeredPlayer" runat="server" AutoPlay="true" Height="400px" Width="400px">
    </telerik:RadMediaPlayer>
</div>
```

and

```
    .centeredPlayer
    {
        margin: auto;
    }
```

If it does not work for you, inspect the rendered HTML to see what CSS is in play. Substitute RadMediaPlayer with a simple div and center that first.